# HTML video background with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, heroku, html5-video, ujs

I am a beginner on Ruby on rails and I am building an application in which have a Video Header Background. The application works fine locally, but once I tried to upload it to Heroku the video-background does not play.
The app is still in development.

I get in my Web-browser console the following messages:

```
HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource https://serene-fortress-58125.herokuapp.com/assets/Islands.mp4 failed. 
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

I am thinking that I should host the video in some sort of hosting service to make it available to the Heroku app, but I need to figure out how that could work with my current html code and which hosting service to use. I tried with tinypic to host the video, but the video was played as x-shockwave-flash and not compatible with my current web design.

I was thinking of using the tubular jquery plug in as adviced in the following post and using Youtube as host:

[Fullscreen video background - <video> vs YouTube/Vimeo-<iframe>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33677763/fullscreen-video-background-video-vs-youtube-vimeo-iframe)

I would maybe need a couple of advices on how to use jquery with Ruby on Rails 5.0.1 and what would be the best practice to make this work out. Any advice would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot

Fabrizio

This is my app on Heroku:
https://serene-fortress-58125.herokuapp.com/

This is my git: 
https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/portfolio

This are links to similar unanswered questions on Stackoverflow:

[adding an animated background to a ruby on rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744915/adding-an-animated-background-to-a-ruby-on-rails-app)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319525/ruby-on-rails-html5-video-as-background-for-landing-page-not-loading-on-heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 404 error message is because i needed to use the rails video_tags and not the html  tags. I was helped from a friend in finding the solution, the following document helped.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline